# How can I share a struct in OOP program?

Tags: c++, struct

I'm writing a code that it's OOP and I need to share a struct between files. I put my struct at end of my .h file and include it. Such as:

```
struct icsData
{
    AudioBuilder *audioBPtr;
}icsDataPtr;
```

Then I got the following errors:

```
NetworkSocket.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `icsDataPtr'
main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
AudioCore.o:(.bss+0x10): multiple definition of `icsDataPtr'
main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
AudioBuilder.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `icsDataPtr'
main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
AudioInterface.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `icsDataPtr'
main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
ChannelEndpoint.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `icsDataPtr'
main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
Device.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `icsDataPtr'
main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
MainCore.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `icsDataPtr'
main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
MicroHandShake.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `icsDataPtr'
main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
FrameBuilder.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `icsDataPtr'
main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
RealTimeStatus.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `icsDataPtr'
main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [eCom] Error 1
```

Question:
Can I share it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `extern` keyword, then define it in one translation unit:

Header file:

```
struct icsData
{
    AudioBuilder *audioBPtr;
};

extern icsData icsDataPtr;
```

Some cpp file:

```
icsData icsDataPtr;
```

Just note that this isn't really object oriented. You might want to create a static class providing one instance of the pointer or simply make the class a singleton, depending on how many common objects you'd like to share. Global objects or variables should be avoided if possible.

Comment: You solved my problem with by single tone class.But now , i can't pass correct data.

Comment: You should be more elaborate on that - or better: create a new question with example code or whatever you've done.

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem ,'because i changed to struct' i have mutiple source file and one header file, and need to define one instance and use it in all of file

Comment: That's exactly what `extern` enables you to do. Are you sure you're doing it right? If ther's a `extern` in front, no instance is created (it's just hinted at it being somewhere else; like a forward declaration). You still need one instance in a single translation unit without `extern` so you actually instanciate it once.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define it on one place. Defining it in a header file, you'll have as many multiple definitions, as source files include that header file.

Define it in one `cpp` file, and use `extern` for the others. For example

```
// cpp1
struct icsData
{
    AudioBuilder *audioBPtr;
}icsDataPtr;


// cpp2
struct icsData;
extern icsData icsDataPtr;
```

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem , i have mutiple source file and one header file, and need to define `one` instance and use it in all of file.

Comment: @seg_fault - writing the code, given for `cpp2` in my answer in you cpp files does not work? Did you try it at all?

Comment: oh no, i define your `struct` in header file.

Comment: @seg_fault - exactly, that's why you get that error. Whatever, it's important, that your question is answered :)

Comment: instead of comment i answer me as new issue , because putting code is nicely in answers.